# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;I)V with IE and Selenium through Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, guava

I am trying to use selenium with sikuli.So sikuli would not run on a 64 bit using the current java set up so in my project changed the runtime to point to a 32 bit runtime environment  and added my selenium jars using the 32 bit iewebdriver now I have a problem with the above Looked every where on the net added the guava.jar file v.21 it did not solve the problem changed that to the guava 26jre.jar and still nothing is working here is my code and errors if anyone can spot where I am going wrong

error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;I)V
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.usingPort(DriverService.java:285)
at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.setupService(InternetExplorerDriver.java:242)
at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.<init>(InternetExplorerDriver.java:211)
at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.<init>(InternetExplorerDriver.java:150)
at riOSikuliAutomation.RiOSikuliAutomation.main(RiOSikuliAutomation.java:33)
```

and here is my code

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
cap.setCapability("nativeEvents", false);
cap.setCapability("unexpectedAlertBehaviour", "accept");
cap.setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", true);
cap.setCapability("disable-popup-blocking", true);
cap.setCapability("enablePersistentHover", true);
cap.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting", true);
cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);
InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
options.merge(cap);
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Users\\Selenium\\IEDriverServer.exe");
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
```

as soon as it reads the last line the error pops up, anything I am not doing right please advise ?

[image: my dependencies]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;I)V
```

...implies that the *IEDriverServer* was unable to initiate/spawn a new *WebBrowsing Session* i.e. *InternetExplorer Browser* session.

Your main issue is the *incompatibility* between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You have mentioned about using **guava-21.0-jre.jar** which is pretty *ancient*.

### Solution

Solution to your question would be either/all of the following steps:

- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.14.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/) which includes **guava-25.0-jre**.
- Upgrade *Guava* to  current levels of **26.0-jre** (as per *Selenium v3.14.0* Java clients).

  - Maven Dependency is as follows:

    ```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>26.0-jre</version>
    </dependency>
    ```
- Ensure you don't have several versions in your dependency tree.

  - To look for the existing guava versions through *Maven* use the command:

    ```
    mvn dependency:tree | less
    ```
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If issue still persists delete the `MAVEN_HOME` directory `.m2` and download the *binaries* afresh.

Comment: @Tim Upvote the answer if this/any answer is/was helpful to you for the benefit of the future readers.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem, however the actual reason is that I used `com.google.collections#google-collections` and `com.google.guava#guava` at the same time in my project, which both declared class `com.google.common.base.Preconditions`, and result into a confliction.

Class defination confliction is a really annoying problem in java project.

Here I recommend a EASY TO USE toolkit [arthas](https://github.com/alibaba/arthas), you can find wihch jar is used when loading a class, or dump the real using bytecode in JVM into a .class file with it.